# Unix Timestamp Conversion Back To Daylight Saving

Tags: php, mysql, time, timezone, dst

Looks like I am having a case of Monday morning!!!

### Setup

As you can my local machine is in Eastern time zone with Day light Saving is in effect. That can be seen from 'date' command below.

```
date ; php -r 'echo mktime() .PHP_EOL ;'
Mon Apr 18 11:14:29 EDT 2016
1460992469
```

I then generated a unix timestamp using php. It is suppose to give your current time and convert that to Unix epoch at UTC 0:0:0 on Jan 1 1970.

My mysql Session is set to UTC, which I imagine 1460992469 represent as it is converted to UTC by mktime.

### The Problem

The trouble is the conversion back to est does not recognizes Daylight Saving. Can anyone help to point the flaw in my logic.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(1460992469), @@session.time_zone ,'EST') as converted_to_est , FROM_UNIXTIME(1460992469) , @@session.time_zone;
+---------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
| converted_to_est    | FROM_UNIXTIME(1460992469) | @@session.time_zone |
+---------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-04-18 10:14:29 | 2016-04-18 15:14:29       | UTC                 |
+---------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
```

I tried using 'EDT' in CONVERT_TZ to no avail already .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `'EST'`.  Use `'America/New_York'` (assuming United States).